# Record Not Show If I use Period and Date Filter in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, filter

I have query that show beginning Stock, Total in, Total Out and final stock. I have 6 tables using in this query: tb_barang, tb_opname_barang, tb_lpb_barang_h, tb_lpb_barang_d, tb_pengeluaran_barang_h, tb_pengeluaran_barang_d. The data I want to display is based on tb_opname_barang which has more than 500 rows for each period. And date filter I use for table tb_lpb_barang_h and tb_lpb_barang_d (Total In) also for table tb_pengeluaran_barang_h and tb_pengeluaran_barang_d (Total Out). If I use period and date filter the record show only data which have full value of each column. But if I don't use period the record show all data from tb_opname_barang even if some column have null value.

This is query if I don't use period n date filter:

```
select tbinout.kode_barang,tbinout.nama_barang,
    sum(tbinout.[Stock Awal]) as [Stock Awal],
    sum(tbinout.[Total Terima]) as [Total Terima], 
    sum(tbinout.[Total Keluar]) as [Total Keluar],
    ((sum(tbinout.[Stock Awal])+sum(tbinout.[Total Terima]))-sum(tbinout.[Total Keluar])) as [Stock Akhir]   
    from(select opb.kode_barang,barang.nama_barang,opb.periode,ter_bh.tgl_terima,
        (Case When opb.stock_sekarang is null Then 0 Else opb.stock_sekarang End) as [Stock Awal],
        (Case When ter_bd.jml_terima is null Then 0 Else ter_bd.jml_terima End) as [Total Terima], 
        (Case When kel_bd.jml_keluar is null then 0 Else kel_bd.jml_keluar End) as [Total Keluar]
        from tb_opname_barang as opb 
        left join tb_barang as barang on opb.kode_barang=barang.kode_barang 
        left join tb_lpb_barang_d as ter_bd on barang.kode_barang=ter_bd.kode_barang 
        left join tb_lpb_barang_h as ter_bh on ter_bd.no_lpb_h=ter_bh.no_lpb_h
        left join tb_pengeluaran_barang_d as kel_bd on barang.kode_barang=kel_bd.kode_barang
        left join tb_pengeluaran_barang_h as kel_bh on kel_bd.kode_h=kel_bh.kode_h) as tbinout
--where tbinout.periode='September-2014' and  tbinout.tgl_terima>='2014-10-01' and tbinout.tgl_terima<='2014-10-31' 
group by tbinout.kode_barang,tbinout.nama_barang
```

above query show 574 rows based on tb_opname_barang (sept periode)

and this is query if I use period n date filter

```
select tbinout.kode_barang,tbinout.nama_barang,
    sum(tbinout.[Stock Awal]) as [Stock Awal],
    sum(tbinout.[Total Terima]) as [Total Terima], 
    sum(tbinout.[Total Keluar]) as [Total Keluar],
    ((sum(tbinout.[Stock Awal])+sum(tbinout.[Total Terima]))-sum(tbinout.[Total Keluar])) as [Stock Akhir]   
    from(select opb.kode_barang,barang.nama_barang,opb.periode,ter_bh.tgl_terima,
        (Case When opb.stock_sekarang is null Then 0 Else opb.stock_sekarang End) as [Stock Awal],
        (Case When ter_bd.jml_terima is null Then 0 Else ter_bd.jml_terima End) as [Total Terima], 
        (Case When kel_bd.jml_keluar is null then 0 Else kel_bd.jml_keluar End) as [Total Keluar]
        from tb_opname_barang as opb 
        left join tb_barang as barang on opb.kode_barang=barang.kode_barang 
        left join tb_lpb_barang_d as ter_bd on barang.kode_barang=ter_bd.kode_barang 
        left join tb_lpb_barang_h as ter_bh on ter_bd.no_lpb_h=ter_bh.no_lpb_h
        left join tb_pengeluaran_barang_d as kel_bd on barang.kode_barang=kel_bd.kode_barang
        left join tb_pengeluaran_barang_h as kel_bh on kel_bd.kode_h=kel_bh.kode_h) as tbinout
where tbinout.periode='September-2014' and  tbinout.tgl_terima>='2014-10-01' and tbinout.tgl_terima<='2014-10-31' 
group by tbinout.kode_barang,tbinout.nama_barang
```

Above query shows only 41 rows (tb_opname_barang periode sept 2014 has 517)

How to show full record based on tb_opname_barang and also with using period n date filter?

Comment: You have date filter for October but comparing records of sept

Comment: of course if i take begining stock of Okt i will use data from stock opname sept right :)